# Azure Application Gateway not showing VM from other VNet in backend pool

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway

When setting up the Backend pools of an Azure Application Gateway, I want to set a specific VM in the pool.

This VM is in another VNet, and I've set up peering between the App Gateway's VNet and the VM's VNet.

Still, when I choose Virtual Machine as the target type of the Backend pool, the list is empty and I don't see any VM.

What's the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the  Azure VM located in the same region as the Azure application gateway? If not, you need to use APP GW V2 version.

Comment: The App GW and the VMs are in the same region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you only could see VMs in the same VNet as the application gateway located when you select the **virtual machine**  as the target type of the backend pool.

If you have VNet peering, you can just add the **internal IP** of the VM to target the backend pool.

A backend pool routes request to backend servers, which serve the request. Backend pools can contain:

> - NICs
> - Virtual machine scale sets
> - Public IP addresses
> - **Internal IP addresses**
> - FQDN
> - Multitenant backends (such as App Service)
>
> If you use internal IPs as backend pool members, you must use virtual
> network peering or a VPN gateway. Virtual network peering is supported
> and beneficial for load-balancing traffic in other virtual networks.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components#backend-pools